# mongodb, make increment several times in single update

Tags: mongodb

Having very simple 2 mongo documents:

```
{_id:1, v:1}
{_id:2, v:1}
```

Now, basing on array of `_id` I need increase field `v` as many times how _id appears. For example `[1, 2, 1]` should produce

```
{_id:1, v:3} //increased 2 times
{_id:2, v:2} //increased 1 times
```

Of course simple update eliminates duplicate in `$in`:

```
db.r.update({_id:{$in:[1,2,1]}}, {$inc:{v:1}}, {multi:true})
```

Is there a way to do it without for-loop? /Thank you in advance/

Comment: I wish there was a way the answers could be merged so we can both take credit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't a way to do this in a single update statement.

The reason why the $in operator "removes the duplicate" is a simple matter of the fact that th `1` was already matched, no point in matching again.  So you can't make the document "match twice" as it were.

Also there is no *current* way to **batch** update operations. But [that feature](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4004) is coming.

You *could* look at your "batch" and make a decision to group together occurrences of the same document to be updated and then issue your increment to the appropriate number of units. However just like looping the array items, the operation would be programitic, albeit a little more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't possible directly. You'll have to do that in your client, where you can at least try to minimize the number of batch updates required.

First, find the counts. This depends on your programming language, but what you want is something like `[1, 2, 1] => [ { 1 : 2 }, { 2 : 1} ]` (these are the counts for the respective ids, i.e. id `1` appears twice, etc.) Something like linq oder underscore.js is helpful here.

Next, since you can't perform different updates in a single operation, group them by their count, and update all objects whose count must be incremented by a common fixed value in one batch:

Pseudocode:

```
var groups = data.groupBy(p => p.Value);
foreach(var group in groups)
    db.update({"_id" : { $in : group.values.asArray }}, 
              // increase by the number of times those ids were present
              {$inc : { v : group.key } })
```

That is better than individual updates only if there are many documents that must be increased by the same value.

Comment: And there is the pseudo-code for what I described. Well done.

Comment: In my defense, I started to code this before reading your answer. But we kind of think alike anyhow. +1 to you, sir.

Comment: No offence taken. This answer stands as an example of "what you should be doing" and deserves credit in it's own right. +1 back at you.